# Trying detect faces on image using face-api.js.Getting error: Unhandled Rejection (Error): createCanvasFromMedia -media has not finished loading yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, face-api

I am struggling with this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js';

const FaceDetect = ({ image }) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef();

    const FaceModelFunc = async () => {

        const canvass = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(image);

        canvasRef.current.innerHTML = canvass;

        const displaySize = {
            width: image.width,
            height: image.height
        };


        faceapi.matchDimensions(canvasRef.current, displaySize);

        const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(image, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions();

        const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);

        canvasRef.current.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height);// clearrect is basically erasing the canvas background by turning
        // // it transparent black 
        faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvasRef.current, resizedDetections);
        faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvasRef.current, resizedDetections);
        faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvasRef.current, resizedDetections, .05);



    }


    useEffect(() => {
        const laodModels = async () => {

            Promise.all([
                faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('./models'),
                faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('./models'),
                faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('./models'),
                faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('./models')

            ]).then(() => FaceModelFunc());
        }

        laodModels();

    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <img src={image} />
            <canvas ref={canvasRef} />

        </>);


}

export default FaceDetect;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on this recently as well. This is what works for me.

TLDR: I think using `const canvas = faceapi.createCanvas(video);`
instead of
`const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video.srcObject);`
Fixed the issue for me. I then just had to manually overlap the canvas ontop of the video with some css:

```
#video {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 450px;
}

#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 450px;
  z-index: 10;
}

#video-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Full updated code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import * as faceapi from "face-api.js";
import WebCam from "react-webcam";

const LiveML = () => {
  const [video, setVideo] = useState(null);
  const [canvas, setCanvas] = useState(null);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const height = 560;
  const width = 720;
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  // Load models on page load
  useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all([
      faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri("/models"),
      faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri("/models"),
      faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri("/models"),
      faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri("/models"),
    ]).then(() => {
      if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        setVideo(document.getElementById("video"));
        navigator.mediaDevices
          .getUserMedia({ audio: false, video: true })
          .then(function (stream) {
            //Display the video stream in the video object
            video.srcObject = stream;
            //Play the video stream
            video.play();
            setIsLoaded(true);
            console.log("Video : " + video);
            addEvent();
          })
          .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e.name + ": " + e.message);
          });
      }

      function addEvent() {
        video.addEventListener("play", () => {
          console.log("addEvent");
          //const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video.srcObject);
          const canvas = faceapi.createCanvas(video);
          //video.append(canvas);
          canvas.id = "canvas";
          document.querySelector("#video").append(canvas);
          document.body.append(canvas);
          const displaySize = { width: width, height: height };
          faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);
          setInterval(async () => {
            const detections = await faceapi
              .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions())
              .withFaceLandmarks()
              .withFaceExpressions();
            const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(
              detections,
              displaySize
            );
            canvas
              .getContext("2d")
              .clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
            faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections);
            faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
          }, 100);
          console.log("Event added");
        });
      }

      console.log("models loaded");
    });
  }, []);

  console.log("Ready!");
  return (
    <div className="video-container">
      {/*<video
        id="video"
        //src={video}
        ref={videoRef}
        autoPlay={true}
        playsInline
        muted
        style={{ width: "720px", height: "560px" }}
      />*/}
      <WebCam
        id="video"
        //src={video}
        ref={videoRef}
        autoPlay={true}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        playsInline
        muted
        style={{ width: "720px", height: "560px" }}
      />
      <canvas
        id="canvas"
        ref={canvasRef}
        style={{ width: "720px", height: "560px" }}
      />
    </div>
  );
  //}
};

export default LiveML;
```

Let me know if this helps or if you found a better solution already.

[Picture of it working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJBKk.png)