# ReactJS - Faceapi.js Error: toNetInput - expected media type issue

Tags: reactjs, p5.js, face-api, tfjs-node

I am new to reactjs and building a page/component for uploading an image and running it through faceapi.js to show face landmark points. I am trying to get these points in an array to be used for some other process later on.

The webcam version works then I tried to do my photo based version; however, been struggling with the below.

The current error I get:

```
toNetInput.ts:39 
    
   Uncaught (in promise) Error: toNetInput - expected media to be of type HTMLImageElement | HTMLVideoElement | HTMLCanvasElement | tf.Tensor3D, or to be an element id
```

I tried defining this from an image element in the Dom as well but didn't work. I feel like I am missing something very simple but too blind to see it...

```js
import React, { useRef , useEffect, useState} from "react";    
import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js'; 

//this one was for previous tests with img html element
import * as inputImage from '../assets/images/sah.png';



function CompName() { 
    loadModels();
    const [file, setFile] = useState([])
    const [canvas, setcanvas] = useState([])

    function fileChangeHandler(event){
      
        setFile(event);
            }
    
    useEffect(() => {
        
       setcanvas(faceapi.createCanvas(file))
        console.log('file 1 ', file.size);
        document.body.append(canvas) 
        if(file.size>0){
        detectF();
        console.log('file ', file);
    }
      }, [file])





     async function loadModels(){
        Promise.all([ 
        await faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/models') ,
        await faceapi.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromUri('/models'),
        await faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/models'),
        await  faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/models'),
        await  faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/models') 
        ]).then((values) => {

            console.log('models loaded');
        });
      } 





    const displaySize = {
        width: file.width,
        height: file.height
      }


    faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize)   
 
    async function detectF(){
        const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(file, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks()
        const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize)
      
      // faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections)
      faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections)
      // faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections)
      const landmarkPositions = resizedDetections[0].landmarks.positions;
 
    console.log({detections});

    }





return (  
    <> 
<div >
<input type="file" onChange={(e) => fileChangeHandler(e.target.files[0])} />
{/* <img src={inputImage} onLoad={handleImageLoad} /> */} 
</>
    );
}

export default CompName;
```

Any help is valuable, thanks in advance.

Here are the sources I've gone through that could be helpful.
[Trying detect faces on image using face-api.js.Getting error: Unhandled Rejection (Error): createCanvasFromMedia -media has not finished loading yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219048/trying-detect-faces-on-image-using-face-api-js-getting-error-unhandled-rejectio)

[face-api.js load image file from disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53685344/face-api-js-load-image-file-from-disk)

[Trying detect faces on image using face-api.js.Getting error: Unhandled Rejection (Error): createCanvasFromMedia -media has not finished loading yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219048/trying-detect-faces-on-image-using-face-api-js-getting-error-unhandled-rejectio)

https://github.com/k3nnet/image_recognition/blob/master/src/app/image-component/image-component.component.ts

https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js

https://medium.com/@kkmphele/image-facial-recognition-in-javascript-using-convolutional-neural-networks-with-face-api-js-7ce8a8c7493c

Answer (score 0):

`const img = await faceapi.bufferToImage(file);`

first of all, you have to use to faceapi buffer function to pass an image

the removing promise .all and setting a state which let us know when is module is loaded.

after we load the module we can give the user the choice to upload an image.

here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-germain-vlyhc0?file=/src/App.js

[Working Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lQLN.jpg)

let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks! Codesandbox didn't show the landmarks(was hidden in the back on Firefox I think) but I managed to eventually got it working on my local. I am trying to pass the array[landmarkList] to the p5 sketch. I added the code into the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-hellman-sqk136?file=/src/App.js
 
It is not working, I think it is about the order of execution?

Comment: it takes time to draw the sketch you have to wait a few seconds and I don't see any changes to code what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason it didn't save my changes, updated again. Basically trying to pass the array/landmarkList to the p5wrapper.

Comment: you can get your landmark like this `const landmarkPositions = await faceapi.detectFaceLandmarks(img);`

Comment: Yea I have them in an array already. What I am trying to do is passing this to the wrapper as props